# Unwrapped tags are still there

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to remove `script` and `noscript` tags under the given tag (node).

```
for t in node.find_all(["script", "noscript"]):
    t.unwrap()

for s in node.stripped_strings:
  print s
```

But the above loop will still print the content of `script` tags.

Where is the fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method you can use the [`decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) method to do this, especially if you don't need to return the tag or string that you want to remove.

> Tag.decompose() removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its contents.

```
for t in node.find_all(["script", "noscript"]):
    t.decompose()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`extract()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) instead:

> `PageElement.extract()` removes a tag or string from the tree.

```
for t in node.find_all(["script", "noscript"]):
    t.extract()
```